# Get Window Z-Order with Python Windows Extensions

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, z-order

Is there a way to get the z-order of windows using the [Python Windows Extensions](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/)? Or, alternatively, is there a way to do this using another module? The usual way to do this is with [`GetTopWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633514%28VS.85%29.aspx) and `GetNextWindow`, but neither of those functions appear in the `win32gui` module.

Currently I'm doing this, but it doesn't take into account the z-order of windows:

```
import win32gui
def get_windows():
    def callback(hwnd, lst):
        lst.append(hwnd)
    lst = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, lst)
    return lst
```

Ideally I'd like something like this: (this doesn't work)

```
import win32gui
import win32con
def get_windows():
    '''Returns windows in z-order (top first)'''
    lst = []
    top = win32gui.GetTopWindow()
    if top is None: return lst
    lst.append(top)
    while True:
        next = win32gui.GetNextWindow(lst[-1], win32con.GW_HWNDNEXT)
        if next is None: break
        lst.append(next)
    return lst
```

However, the `GetTopWindow` and `GetNextWindow` functions are missing, so I can't.

**UPDATE:**

I guess I was a little too quick to ask for help. I figured it out using ctypes. Hopefully someone else finds this helpful.

```
import win32con
import ctypes
def get_windows():
    '''Returns windows in z-order (top first)'''
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
    lst = []
    top = user32.GetTopWindow(None)
    if not top:
        return lst
    lst.append(top)
    while True:
        next = user32.GetWindow(lst[-1], win32con.GW_HWNDNEXT)
        if not next:
            break
        lst.append(next)
    return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Necroposting.

*PyWin32*'s current *URL*: [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32).

Regarding the *CTypes* alternative:

- Should probably be posted in an answer rather than the question
- Contains a common flaw with possibly disastrous consequences. Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for the details

Regarding the *PyWin32* implementation, considering it doesn't contain bugs (I didn't check):

- [[MS.Docs]: GetNextWindow macro (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getnextwindow) (as the *URL* text states), **is a *#define*** to *GetWindow* not a function, fact that was known at question time (as *CTypes* implementation is using the latter), so *win32gui.GetWindow* can be used (at least in latest *PyWin32* versions)
- I've just submitted **[[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - More window functions in win32gui](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/pull/1928)** (merged to *main* on *220822*). Check [[SO]: How to change username of job in print queue using python & win32print (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71684828/4788546) for details on how to benefit from such a patch. 
  Local build example:

  > ```
  > [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\GitHub\CristiFati\pywin32\src\build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\win32]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import os;os.add_dll_directory(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()), 'pywin32_system32'));import win32gui as wgui;print(wgui);print('Top window handle: 0x{:016X}'.format(wgui.GetTopWindow(None)))"
  > <module 'win32gui' from 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\GitHub\\CristiFati\\pywin32\\src\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.9\\win32\\win32gui.pyd'>
  > Top window handle: 0x0000000000020480
  > ```