# How to change username of job in print queue using python & win32print

Tags: python, winapi, printing, pywin32

I am trying to change the user of a print job in the queue, as I want to create it on a service account but send the job to another users follow-me printing queue. I'm using the win32 module in python. Here is an example of my code:

```
from win32 import win32print

JOB_INFO_LEVEL = 2
pclExample = open("sample.pcl")
printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
hPrinter = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)

try:
    jobID = win32print.StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, ("PCL Data test", None, "RAW"))
    # Here we try to change the user by extracting the job and then setting it again
    jobInfoDict = win32print.GetJob(hPrinter, jobID , JOB_INFO_LEVEL )
    jobInfoDict["pUserName"] = "exampleUser"
    win32print.SetJob(hPrinter, jobID , JOB_INFO_LEVEL  , jobInfoDict , win32print.JOB_CONTROL_RESUME )

    try:
        win32print.StartPagePrinter(hPrinter)
        win32print.WritePrinter(hPrinter, pclExample)
        win32print.EndPagePrinter(hPrinter)

    finally:
        win32print.EndDocPrinter(hPrinter)
finally:
    win32print.ClosePrinter(hPrinter)
```

The problem is I get an error at the win32print.SetJob() line. If JOB_INFO_LEVEL is set to 1, then I get the following error:

```
(1804, 'SetJob', 'The specified datatype is invalid.')
```

This is a known bug to do with how the C++ works in the background ([Issue here](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1281)).

If JOB_INFO_LEVEL is set to 2, then I get the following error:

```
(1798, 'SetJob', 'The print processor is unknown.')
```

However, this is the processor that came from win32print.GetJob(). Without trying to change the user this prints fine, so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Any help would be hugely appreciated! :)

**EDIT:**

Using Python 3.8.5 and Pywin32 303

Comment: Perhaps It's a `pywin32` issue but I haven’t verified [SetJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/setjob) function.

Comment: What are your *Python* and *PyWin32* versions?

Comment: Using Python 3.8.5 and Pywin32 303 - Just added to original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning I thought it was a misunderstanding (I was also a bit skeptical about the bug report), mainly because of the following paragraph (which apparently **seems to be wrong**) from [[MS.Docs]: SetJob function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/setjob) (***emphasis*** is mine):

> The following members of a [JOB_INFO_1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/job-info-1), [JOB_INFO_2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/job-info-2), or [JOB_INFO_4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/job-info-4) structure ***are ignored*** on a call to **SetJob**: **JobId**, **pPrinterName**, **pMachineName**, **pUserName**, **pDrivername**, **Size**, **Submitted**, **Time**, and **TotalPages**.

But I did some tests and ran into the problem. The problem is as described in the bug: filling *JOB_INFO_** string members (which are *LPTSTR*s) with *char** data.

Submitted **[[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Fix: win32print.SetJob sending ANSI to UNICODE API](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/pull/1849)** (and **none of the 2 errors** pops up). It was merged to *main* on *220331*.

When testing the fix, I was able to change various properties of an existing job, I was amazed that **it didn't have to be valid data** (like below), I'm a bit curious to see what would happen when the job would be executed (as now I don't have a connection to a printer):

- Change *pUserName* to `str(random.randint(0, 10000))` to make sure it changes on each script run (*PrintScreen*s taken separately and assembled in *Paint*):

  [image: img0]

#### Ways to go further:

1. Wait for a new *PyWin32* version (containing this fix) to be released. **This is the recommended approach**, but it will also take more time (and it's unclear when it will happen)
2. Get the sources, either:

- from *main*
- from *b303* (last stable branch), and apply the (above) patch<sup>***(1)***</sup>

  build the module (*.pyd*) and copy it in the *PyWin32*'s *site-packages* directory on your *Python* installation(s). Faster, but it requires some deeper knowledge, and maintenance might become a nightmare

---

#### Footnotes

- ***#1***: Check [[SO]: Run / Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989490/4788546) (**Patching *UTRunner*** section) for how to apply patches (on *Win*).

Comment: Thanks Cristi - I've marked this as accepted as it solved the issue and I now have access to changing the user.

I was wondering what JOB_CONTROL_* variable you passed into the job control parameter to change the user? I am able to execute the command, but it doesn't change the owner in the queue.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to that detail, I just used whatever value was in the script in the bug report *URL*, and that is ***0***. "*You can use the same call to the **SetJob** function to set print job parameters and to give a command to a print job. Thus, Command does not need to be 0 if you are setting print job parameters, although it can be.*"