# Can't reproduce audio file using python pyo library

Tags: python, audio, pyo

I'm testing pyo library and I can't reproduce any audio file. Here's the sample code:

```
from pyo import *

s = Server().boot()

path = SNDS_PATH + r"/05.Black Alien - Take Ten"

sf = SfPlayer(path, speed=[1, 0.995], loop=True, mul=0.4).out()

s.gui(locals())
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/UFPA/2022.2/Programação I/SpotifyPremiumMelhorado1/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    sf = SfPlayer(path, speed=[1, 0.995], loop=True, mul=0.4).out()
  File "D:\UFPA\2022.2\Programação I\SpotifyPremiumMelhorado1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyo\lib\players.py", line 116, in __init__
    _snd_size, _dur, _snd_sr, _snd_chnls, _format, _type = sndinfo(path[0])
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *sndinfo* could not get file info. Are you sure the path is correct (the extension is missing)? You could verify it by `os.path.isfile(path)`.

*PyO* produces a misleading error / stacktrace.
To fix that, I submitted [[GitHub]: belangeo/pyo - Raise exception on error](https://github.com/belangeo/pyo/pull/246) (**merged on *220930*** (after a few additional commits)).
Check [[SO]: How to change username of job in print queue using python & win32print (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71684828/4788546) (at the end) for possible ways to go further.