# win32com.client combrowse.main() (Python Object Browser) is not responding Python 3.9

Tags: python, windows, com, pywin32, win32com

I have tried doing this on 2 separate installations of python 3.9 on different computers which don't work and one of 3.5 and it does work on 3.5 on a third computer.

The code:

```
from win32com.client import combrowse
combrowse.main()
```

I have also tried adding a time.sleep(100) statement after the combrowse.main and have run it in the python terminal. All of these result in the Python Object Browser opening and immediately crashing (not responding) if I try to click anything. There is no error statement. Task manager doesn't show any significant CPU or ram usage.

Can someone else try running combrowse on 3.9 or 3.10 and see if it will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with *Python*: *v3.7*, *v3.8*, *v3.9*, *v3.10*, and it worked with the 1<sup>st</sup> and failed with the rest. But it turns out that was only a coincidence, because of the different *PyWin32* versions that I installed (at different points in time) for those *Python* versions. After a few more tries, I realized that it's a *PyWin32* regression bug.

In order to only change one variable at a time, I chose *Python 3.**9*** (that I use as main version) and played with different *PyWin32* versions. Results below:

- *v300* - **works**
- *v301* - crashes (with the *Python has stopped working* dialog)
- *v303* - crashes (with the *Python has stopped working* dialog)
- *v304* - crashes (silently)

A (shallow) *Google* search didn't reveal anything relevant, also the error isn't quite trivial, it happens in *PyWin32*'s *.dll*s (as expected). 
In consequence, the only advice I can provide at this point is to downgrade *PyWin32* to *v300*.

If I find some more details, I will share them here.

---

#### Update *#0*

In *v301* some new (dialog display related) functionality was added, and also made the default. That doesn't work (*OOTB*, at least). Fortunately, the old one is still available - with a minor code change:

```py
combrowse.main(modal=True)
```

**It works for all above *PyWin32* versions** (that (normally) fail). A possible drawback is (obviously) the dialog being modal.

---

#### Update *#1*

After a deeper investigation, I think I've got it. Submitted **[[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Fix modeless COM browser dialog](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/pull/1895)**, which fixes the issue:

[image: Img00]

For possible ways to benefit from the fix (**once it's accepted**), check [[SO]: How to change username of job in print queue using python & win32print (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71684828/4788546) (at the end).

The *PR* was rejected (although worth reading the discussion), but the issue was fixed in [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Make modal dialog the default again in combrowse.main()](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/pull/1924). With that fix, `combrowse.main()` will now work.

Comment: @TedBurt: Did you have the time to check the (1st) fix out?